# Finding Marginal Density functions with $Y\sim N_4(\mu,\Sigma)$

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution

Suppose $Y$ is $N_4(\mu, \Sigma)$ where

> $$\mu = ( 1,2,3,-2)'$$
>   and
>
> $$\Sigma =\begin{bmatrix} 
> 4& 2& -1& 2 \\
> 2& 6& 3& -2 \\
> -1& 3& 5& -4 \\
> 2& -2& -4& 4
> \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\Sigma$, the covariance matrix is a $4\times4$ matrix.

(a) Find the marginal distribution of $Y_2$.

(b) Find the joint marginal distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_3$.

(c) Find the distribution of $Z = Y_1 + 2Y_2 - Y_3 + 3Y_4$.

Some questions that I have:

1) What does $N_4$ mean?

*Edits*

2) For part a, is it right to say $Y_2$ is of $N(2, 6)$ from the above $\Sigma$ and $\mu$? I am unsure how the marginal distribution is gotten for $Y_2$ from a group of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4$, inside the vector $Y$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Here you have a guide to format expressions with MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You are right, that $Y_2\sim \mathcal N(2,6)$.

Comment: @iadvd Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N_4(\mu,\Sigma)$ is the pdf of [the multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). The marginal distributions are normal distributions whose parameters are given in the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and in the expectation vector $\mu$.

If you recall the definition the entries of the covariance matrix, $\Sigma$, $$\sigma_{i,j}=E[(Y_i-\mu_i)(Y_j-\mu_j)].$$ and $$\mu_i=E[Y_i].$$ 
Specifically, the variance of $Y_2$, $\sigma_{Y_2}^2=\sigma_{2,2}=6$ and the expectation of $Y_2$, $m_{Y_2}=\mu_2=2$. So, the distribution of $Y_2$ is $N_1(2,6)$.

The common distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_3$ is also normal ($N_2(\mu_{Y_1,Y_3},\Sigma_{Y_1,Y_3})$ with the covariance matrix

$$\Sigma_{Y_1,Y_3}=
\begin{bmatrix}
4&-1\\
-1&5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and expectation vector 
$$\mu_{Y_1,Y_3}=(1,3)'.$$

As far as the distribution of $Z = Y_1 + 2Y_2 - Y_3 + 3Y_4$; it is normal with expectation

$$m_Z=E[Z]=\mu_1+2\mu_2-\mu_3+3\mu_4=-4.$$

The variance of $Z$ can be easily calculated now considering that

$$\sigma_Z^2=E[Z^2]-E^2[Z].$$

($E[Z^2]=E[(Y_1 + 2Y_2 - Y_3 + 3Y_4)^2]$.)

Or
$$\sigma_Z^2=E[Z-m_Z)^2]=E[(Y_1-\mu_1)+2(Y_2-\mu_2)-(Y_3-\mu_3)+3(Y_4-\mu_4))^2].$$

After squaring we are going to have terms that can be calculated. For instance:

$$E[((Y_1-\mu_1)2(Y_2-\mu_2)]=2\sigma_{1,2}=2\cdot2=4.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now :D